# Why does the Python print statement cause a UnicodeEncodeError?

Tags: python, sublimetext

I am using Sublime Text.

I want to print the `s2`, `s3` and `s4` variables:

```
s2 = '∞⟀⟁⟂⟃⟄⟇⟈⟉⟊⟐⟑⟒⟓⟔⟕⟖⟗⟘⟙⟚⟛'

s3 = 'αßáàåäæçéèêíìîñóòôöøúùüž'

s4 = '╵╷╹╻│▏┃┆┇┊╎┋╿╽⌞⌟⌜⌝⌊⌋⌈⌉⌋┌┍┎┏┐┑┒┓└┕┖┗┘┙┚┛'

print(s2,s3,s4)
```

But the `print` statement causes a `UnicodeEncodeError`:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in
> position 0-21: character maps to

Comment: with python3 solve this unicode issue. please try with python3.

Comment: @JignashaRoyala, obviously he is using python 3, look on `print` statement.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: >>> s2 = '∞⟀⟁⟂⟃⟄⟇⟈⟉⟊⟐⟑⟒⟓⟔⟕⟖⟗⟘⟙⟚⟛'
>>> s3 = 'αßáàåäæçéèêíìîñóòôöøúùüž'
>>> s4 = '╵╷╹╻│▏┃┆┇┊╎┋╿╽⌞⌟⌜⌝⌊⌋⌈⌉⌋┌┍┎┏┐┑┒┓└┕┖┗┘┙┚┛'
>>> print(s2,s3,s4)
∞⟀⟁⟂⟃⟄⟇⟈⟉⟊⟐⟑⟒⟓⟔⟕⟖⟗⟘⟙⟚⟛ αßáàåäæçéèêíìîñóòôöøúùüž ╵╷╹╻│▏┃┆┇┊╎┋╿╽⌞⌟⌜⌝⌊⌋⌈⌉⌋┌┍┎┏┐┑┒┓└┕┖┗┘┙┚┛  with python3 is work fine for me

Comment: I also have no problem printing.

Comment: Windows 10 64 bits, last version and python 3

Comment: i am use sublim text

Comment: @OlvinRoght Not so obvious... that syntax will work with Python 2 also

Comment: Works for me on Linux with Sublime text editor.

Answer (score 1):

No matter which editor you use or which OS you use, this will always work. simply using `sys.stdout.buffer.write()` which is one of the best practices.

```
import sys 

s2 = '∞⟀⟁⟂⟃⟄⟇⟈⟉⟊⟐⟑⟒⟓⟔⟕⟖⟗⟘⟙⟚⟛'
s3 = 'αßáàåäæçéèêíìîñóòôöøúùüž'
s4 = '╵╷╹╻│▏┃┆┇┊╎┋╿╽⌞⌟⌜⌝⌊⌋⌈⌉⌋┌┍┎┏┐┑┒┓└┕┖┗┘┙┚┛'

x = s2.encode('utf8')
y = s3.encode('utf8')
z = s4.encode('utf8')

# you can use loops if you want, python is fun!
sys.stdout.buffer.write(x)
print("")
sys.stdout.buffer.write(y)
print("")
sys.stdout.buffer.write(z)
print("")
```

---

#### output:

```
∞⟀⟁⟂⟃⟄⟇⟈⟉⟊⟐⟑⟒⟓⟔⟕⟖⟗⟘⟙⟚⟛
αßáàåäæçéèêíìîñóòôöøúùüž
╵╷╹╻│▏┃┆┇┊╎┋╿╽⌞⌟⌜⌝⌊⌋⌈⌉⌋┌┍┎┏┐┑┒┓└┕┖┗┘┙┚┛
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.encode("utf-8")` to string.
For example `s2.encode("utf-8")` that worked for me.

Comment: unreadable:   b'\xe2\x88\x9e\xe2\x9f\x80\xe2\x9f\x81\xe2\x9f\x82\xe2\x9f\x83\xe2\x9f\x84\xe2\x9f\x87\xe2\x9f\x88\xe2\x9f\x89\xe2\x9f\x8a\xe2\x9f\x90\xe2\x9f\x91\xe2\x9f\x92\xe2\x9f\x93\xe2\x9f\x94\xe2\x9f\x95\xe2\x9f\x96\xe2\x9f\x97\xe2\x9f\x98\xe2\x9f\x99\xe2\x9f\x9a\xe2\x9f\x9b'

Comment: @Techey encode turns the string into bytes. Why you are suggesting so?

Comment: @llX 61 I thought your problem was similar to [this](https://github.com/llSourcell/twitter_sentiment_challenge/issues/1) thread. Also my problem was not exactly same but it worked for me, so I suggested

Comment: I am use sublim text.

Answer (score 0):

try with UTF-8 stander format with sublime text. it work for me with sublime.
file format like that file save as test3.py

```
#-*- mode: python -*-
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


s2 = '∞⟀⟁⟂⟃⟄⟇⟈⟉⟊⟐⟑⟒⟓⟔⟕⟖⟗⟘⟙⟚⟛'
s3 = 'αßáàåäæçéèêíìîñóòôöøúùüž'

s4 = '╵╷╹╻│▏┃┆┇┊╎┋╿╽⌞⌟⌜⌝⌊⌋⌈⌉⌋┌┍┎┏┐┑┒┓└┕┖┗┘┙┚┛'
print(s2,s3,s4)
```

output:

```
python3 test3.py 
∞⟀⟁⟂⟃⟄⟇⟈⟉⟊⟐⟑⟒⟓⟔⟕⟖⟗⟘⟙⟚⟛ αßáàåäæçéèêíìîñóòôöøúùüž ╵╷╹╻│▏┃┆┇┊╎┋╿╽⌞⌟⌜⌝⌊⌋⌈⌉⌋┌┍┎┏┐┑┒┓└┕┖┗┘┙┚┛
```

Answer (score 0):

I used sublime text and its showing me this error. But when I use Thonny python IDE it shows me very well.